# Adding a new column with State based on StateCode column to every dataframe in a list

Tags: list, mutate

I have a list of dataframes where each dataframe looks like:

```
Year State Code
2017 NY
2017 ID
2017 TX
```

I want to add a column to each dataframe with the state name based on the state code.  I've tried:

```
for (i in 1:length(list)){
  list[[i]] <-  mutate(STATE_NAME = state.name[which(state.abb == "State Code")])
}
```

but I get an error that says:

```
Error in UseMethod("mutate") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "character"
```

I've read the other posts on this (which is where I got the above code) but can't find any on how to do this in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out in case anyone can use it:

```
for (i in 1:length(list)){
  state_name <- state.name[match(list[[i]]$`State Code`, state.abb)]
  list[[i]] <-  add_column(list[[i]], "State" = state_name)
}
```